# How to create Auto layout equal width constraint programmatically in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How to give programmatically constraints equal width and equal height with multiple views.I check google but not perfect answer for programmatically equal width and height constraints through auto layout.

my code look like below:

```
  var countNoOfViews:Int = 3   
 @IBOutlet var viewForRow1: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 self.specialButtonViewLeft()
}

func specialButtonViewLeft(){

    for i in 0..<countNoOfViews{
        var customView:UIView!
        customView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewForRow1.addSubview(customView)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: self.viewForRow1, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: self.viewForRow1, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewForRow1, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: customLeadingSpaceLeft)

        customLeadingSpaceLeft = customLeadingSpaceLeft + customViewWidth

        arrayLeftBtnConstraints.append(widthConstraint)

        if i == 0{
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }else if i == 1{
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }else if i == 2{
            leftViewVal = customLeadingSpaceLeft
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }
        customView.alpha = 0.50
        viewForRow1.addConstraints([widthConstraint, leadingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
    }
}
```

I want to add equal width constraint programmatically.

Comment: were you able to get the job done?

Answer (score 36):

You have three possible ways to do that:

1) By using anchors:

`view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true`

2) Visual format:

simple example - `"H:|[otherView]-[view(==otherView)]|"`

3) "Old school" constraints:

`NSLayoutConstraint(item: #view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: #otherView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true`

hope it will help somebody.

Comment: Or even shorter.. `view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.widthAnchor).isActive = true` :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewForRow1, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0.0)
```

`multiplier: 0.25`, denotes that `customView`'s width will be 1/4th of the parent view, `viewForRow1`.

Comment: Thanks.but i have multiple view divide equal width to super view.And another things i want to change width of programatically auto layout constraints based on orientation like in Portrait - 30 and Landscape - 40 width