# Swift constraint problems with multiply buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to make a simple tic tac toe game in Swift. The code is done but I'm having trouble with the constraints between different devices, for example iPhone 8 to iPhone 8+. The images are on buttons.
Here is a picture to make it easier to see the problem.
[image]

Comment: Are you using stackViews? Stack views make everything so much easier. Especially when you have a lot of buttons on the screen.

Comment: show your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stack views, you should use **Fill Equally as the distribution** in them.

**In Interface Builder**, select the stack view, click on **the Attributes inspector** (the fourth icon from the left on the right sidebar) and select **Fill Equally** for **Distribution** in the **Stack View** section.

[image: "Fill Equally" distribution for stack view in Interface Builder]

...or alternatively, you can do the same **programmatically**:

```
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
```

If you are simply putting the views in a superview, you should set **an equal width and height constraint** to all of them. [Here is an example for a programmatic layout.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40971192/3151675)

Comment: then how the lines can be added ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya They can be added as views on top of the stack view or by modifying the look of it with various `CALayer`s programmatically.

Comment: Yes i know but then is it possible to get exact position where we need to put it ? that is my question

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya You can use constraint multipliers for that or simply dividing the view's width/height to calculate the position you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you helped me solve the problem by equal width and height!

Answer (score 0):

1) You will add a vertical stack view with constraint: width equal to the view width and 1:1 ratio, also an XY position if asked

2) You will add the image as background Image with aspect fit to the vertical stack view and equal distribution

3) You will add 3 horizontal stack views  to the vertical stack view with equal distribution too

4) To each horizontal stack view add 3 buttons with 1:1 ration and add the images to the buttons as background image with aspect fit

I recommend you to leave some space X in the start and the end of the container view in the width and the same amount to leave put in in the space besides the stack views. For example 10.